# Why AWS Device Farm is allowing to only few devices to run tests?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-device-farm

I am working with AWS Device Farm.

I ran tests by selecting some devices randomly it is allowing to run on some devices only. For others it is not allowing to go through. Does anyone know why?

[You can see the image below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MOKnz.jpg)

Comment: How were the tests scheduled? CLI? It may be the case that the app isn't compatible with those devices OS level. Also, at which point did the tests stop? The set up, teardown, or during the tests themselves? 

Can you post logs from the stopped tests?

Comment: What's the timeout of the tests? Look like the successful test was a finished in three minutes but the stopped tests finished in 8 minutes.